# Using dplyr for filtering data table output in shiny

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I have a table output from MySQL in shiny. I have certain filters based on which the table output depends. I am getting the data table as the output but it is not reactive.
I have given the UI and Server details here. Could you let me know why it is not reactive?

```
 unique_values2 <- sort(unique(opponents$opponent))
```

**UI**

```
ui <- navbarPage("Advanced",
             tabPanel("Page One",
                      column(4,radioButtons("firstorsecond", "First Or Second",
                                            choices = c(1:2),selected='1')),

                      column(4,radioButtons("tresult", "T Result",
                                            choices = list("Won" = "Won", "Lost" = "Lost"),selected="Won")),

                      column(4,radioButtons("mresult", "Match Result",
                                            choices = list("Won" = "Won", "Lost" = "Lost", "Tied"="Tied"),selected="Won")),

                      column(4,selectInput("opponent", "Select opponent", choices = unique_values2)),

                      column(4,radioButtons("position", "Position", 
                                            choices = c(1:11),inline = TRUE)),

                      dataTableOutput("values1")
             )
)
```

**SERVER**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {


 df<-dbGetQuery(mydb,"select 
 firstorsecond,position,opponent,tresult,mresult,points
 from customers where cust_id=7830")
 df  

 tablevalues1<-reactive
 ({
  firstorsecond<-as.integer(input$firstorsecond)
  position<-as.integer(input$position)
  opponent<-input$opponent  #String value
  mresult<-input$mresult   #String value
  tresult<-input$toss_result     #String value

  df %>% filter(firstorsecond %in% firstorsecond,position %in% 
  position,opponent %in% opponent,mresult %in% mresult,tresult %in% 
  tresult)
 })

 output$values1 <- renderDataTable({
 tablevalues1()
 })
}
```

Help is very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is probably conflicting variable names. You should probably try something like `mresult %in% input$mresult` for your conditions to avoid ambiguity. Right now the `filter` function probably uses the table columns for LHS and RHS of the operator.

Comment: Apologies.I probably should've been more clear - my data table is not reactive to my input$ variables. The data looks like this - https://ibb.co/1zDBLXN .

Comment: I tried changing the variable names as you suggested, Rohit. But even the data table (sans reactivity to filter) is not being printed now, as opposed to before.

Comment: Can you post a dample of your input dataframe as well as the code you've tried with it's outcome? It would help me to experiment.

Comment: I've added your new code as an edit to your post. It isn't advisable to post more than one expression of code in the comments. Plrease look up the function `dput` to see how you can post your data in a prefferable format

Comment: Okay got it, thanks. I shall delete the comment then. Also, the sample input data frame can be seen in the link in the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edited code you tried does work:

```
tablevalues1<-reactive ({ 
  fos<-as.integer(input$firstorsecond) 
  pos<-as.integer(input$position) 
  opp<-input$opponent 
  match<-input$mresult 
  toss<-input$tresult 
  df %>% filter(firstorsecond %in% fos,position %in% pos, opponent %in% opp,mresult %in% match,tresult %in%toss ) 
})
```

The problem is there are too many filters for such a small dataset. The comma between conditions implies an `AND` condition. It doesn't show any results because there aren't any that match the filter condition. Try with a larger dataset or by matching the inputs to an exact row in your dataframe.

Edit: Using the below code and the  options : 1,1,mresult=Tied,opponent= A, tresult=Lost I got one row in the table output.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage("Advanced",
                 tabPanel("Page One",
                          column(4,radioButtons("firstorsecond", "First Or Second",
                                                choices = c(1:2),selected='1')),

                          column(4,radioButtons("tresult", "T Result",
                                                choices = list("Won" = "Won", "Lost" = "Lost"),selected="Won")),

                          column(4,radioButtons("mresult", "Match Result",
                                                choices = list("Won" = "Won", "Lost" = "Lost", "Tied"="Tied"),selected="Won")),

                          column(4,selectInput("opponent", "Select opponent", choices = c('A','B','C','D'))),

                          column(4,radioButtons("position", "Position", 
                                                choices = c(1:11),inline = TRUE)),

                          dataTableOutput("values1")
                 )
)
df <- data.frame(firstorsecond=c(1,1,2,1,2,1),
                 position=c(1,3,5,8,9,11),
                 opponent=unlist(strsplit('ABCADA','')),
                 mresult=unlist(strsplit('Tied Tied Lost Tied Won Lost',' ')),
                 tresult=unlist(strsplit('Lost Lost Lost Lost Won Lost',' ')),
                 points=c(2,3,4,6,1,3)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {





  tablevalues1<-reactive ({ 
    print(df)
    fos<-as.integer(input$firstorsecond) 

    pos<-as.integer(input$position) 

    opp<-input$opponent 
    match<-input$mresult 
    toss<-input$tresult 
    print(dput(list(fos=fos,pos=pos,opp=opp,match=match,toss=toss)))
    df1 <- df %>% filter(firstorsecond %in% fos , position %in% pos , opponent %in% opp ,mresult %in% match , tresult %in%toss ) 
    print(df1)
    df1
  }) 

 output$values1 <- renderDataTable({
 tablevalues1()
 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me for particular rows in the dataframe. Also, before I choose the filter values, won't the entire table be shown?

Comment: Go through my edit. See if it helps. Also, the inputs already have defaults chosen. It will use those options. If you don't want this, you need to encode that with the necessary checks

Comment: This seems to do the trick! Is there any way I can display the entire dataframe df as default and as I subsequently choose filters, the specific data is shown? Now,  only if I choose the specific filter values, I can see data. Otherwise the table displayed is empty.

Comment: How to do that without having all the filters changed to checkboxGroupInput and selecting all the choices by default?

Comment: Don't give a `selected` arguement in `ui.R`. Then change the filter arguements depending on wether or not the inputs are `NULL`

Comment: I understand but I'm not too sure how to code that part. Could you please elucidate?